# Correctness of iterative DFS for cycle detection

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, graph

I'm attempting the `Graph Algorithms` section in CLRS right now. Here's an iterative DFS using a stack called `nodes`.

`T` is a vector of `pair`(s) of `ints` which store timestamps for each node.

`T[node].first = discovery time`

`T[node].second = finishing time`

`P` is a vector recording Parents for each node in the DFS-Tree.

`N` is number of nodes in a given `Directed Graph`, which is represented using the `Adjacency List` representation as `G`. So `G[node]` represents the `Adjacency List` (as a `vector` of `ints`) for `node` in `G`.

`cycleFound` is a boolean for detecting a cycle in `G`.

```
void stackDFS(vector<vector<int>>& G, vector<pair<int, int>>& T,
    vector<int>& P, int N, bool* cycleFound)
{
    stack<int> nodes;
    int Time = 0;

    int u, v;
    for (u = 1; u <= N; u++)
    {
        if (T[u].first == 0)
        {
            nodes.push(u);

            while (!nodes.empty())
            {
                v = nodes.top();
                nodes.pop();

                if (T[v].first == 0)
                {
                    T[v].first = ++Time;

                    // we push it back before expanding it's children
                    // so it can be popped again and it's
                    // finishing time can be added in "else if".
                    // if it's popped from stack and it's already been
                    // discovered, then by OUR stack's logic, it's children
                    // have already been expanded, so it's fin-time can
                    // now be added.
                    nodes.push(v);

                    for (auto w = G[v].begin(); w != G[v].end(); w++)
                    {
                        if (T[*w].first == 0)
                        {
                            // cout << "Tree Edge encountered...(" << v << ", " << *w << ")" << endl;

                            P[*w] = v;
                            nodes.push(*w);
                        }

                        // this is different from the else-if condition below
                        // here, edges are being examined, and if a back-edge
                        // is found, we say there's a cycle.

                        // Back-Edge: v.d < u.d < u.f < v.f
                        //            for an edge u --> v
                        else if (T[*w].second == 0)
                        {
                            // cout << "Back Edge encountered...(" << v << ", " << *w << ")" << endl;  
                            *cycleFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // don't wanna re-update finish-times again and again
                // cuz that would be wrong computations.
                // A node can be pushed multiple times on stack if 
                // current DFS-path has edges to it from multiple nodes
                // and our node is still marked undiscovered.
                // Eg- node s in graph from CLRS pg 611, fig22.6, ex22.3-2
                // Thus, only update fin-time once, when node finishes
                // for the first time.
                else if (T[v].second == 0)
                    T[v].second = ++Time;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this on two different digraphs, one cyclic and the other acyclic.

`Input 1: 1->2->3->4->5->6; acyclic`

`Input 2: graph from CLRS pg 611, fig22.6; has three cyclic`

It correctly detects cycles and the timestamps computed make sense. So I think this implementation is correct, but I'm not sure. I wrote some comments in the code to explain my logic, but it's mostly intuition. Is this a correct implementation of DFS? Will it always compute timestamps correctly?

Also, how could I classify edges in this code? I'm having trouble classifying Forward and Cross Edges. In recursive DFS it's simpler cuz of the nested recursive structure:

```
void DFSVisit(vector<vector<int>>& G, vector<pair<int, int>>& T, 
    vector<int>& P, int curNode, int* Time, bool* cycleFound)
{
    (*Time)++;
    T[curNode].first = *Time;

    for (auto i = G[curNode].begin(); i != G[curNode].end(); i++)
    {
        if (T[*i].first == 0)
        {
            cout << "Tree Edge encountered...(" << curNode << ", " << *i << ")" << endl; 
            P[*i] = curNode;
            DFSVisit(G, T, P, *i, Time, cycleFound);
        }

        // cycle is present if node (*i) if encountered from curNode
        // such that (*i) hasn't yet finished, meaning (*i) has been
        // encountered again in the current DFS traversal, thus
        // edge (curNode, *i) is a back edge which completes the cycle
        else if (T[*i].second == 0)
        {
            cout << "Back Edge encountered...(" << curNode << ", " << *i << ")" << endl;  
            *cycleFound = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // only specifying condition for discovery times
            // is enough here because T&B edges have already
            // classified above, and for C-edges, *i needs to
            // be discovered first.
            if (T[curNode].first < T[*i].first)
                cout << "Forward Edge encountered...(" << curNode << ", " << *i << ")" << endl;
            else
                cout << "Cross Edge encountered...(" << curNode << ", " << *i << ")" << endl; 
        }
    }

    (*Time)++;
    T[curNode].second = *Time;
}
```

If I try these same conditions in the Iterative DFS, it doesn't work because there's no recursive structure, in other words, all outgoing edges from `current node` are classified as `Tree Edges`, since all outgoing edges are examined together in the `for-loop` in Iterative-DFS, even though some of them might be forward edges.